# Determine a closed form for this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

Every year, 38 % of the amount of fish in a pond die. The 1st of May 2011 there were 5200 fish in the pond. Every year after May 1st 2011, 1900 new fish are added to the pond.

Let $a_n$ be the amount of fish in the pond (directly after new fish have been added) $n$ years after May 1st 2011.

Determine a closed form for this sequence.

How to solve this problem?

My attempt is: $a_n = 5200 - 0,38a_n + 1900n \Rightarrow 1,38a_n = 5200 + 1900n \Rightarrow a_n = \frac{5200 + 1900n}{1,38}$

Comment: You mean $a_{n+1}=0.68a_n+1900$ which will slowly stop growing.

Comment: Oh... Well that's not a closed form

Comment: Nope, but it is a good start, you will notice that $a_1=0.68\cdot 5200+1900$,$a_2=0.68^2\cdot 5200+1900\cdot 0.68$,$a_3=0.68^3\cdot 5200+1900\cdot 0.68^2+1900\cdot 0.68$, see the pattern?

Comment: I have undone an edit that removed vital information from the problem, leaving it in a state where there was no clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would start: $$\begin{align*}a_0 &= 5200 \\ a_1 &= 5200\cdot 0.62+1900 \\ a_2 &= (5200\cdot 0.62+1900)\cdot 0.62 +1900 = 5200\cdot 0.62^2+1900(1+0.62) \\ a_3 &= 5200\cdot 0.62^3+1900(1+0.62+0.62^2) \\ \vdots\end{align*}$$ Can you find a general $a_n$ from here? A fun bonus question is: If the process repeats indefinitely, how many fish will be left at the end?

Comment: Hmm... All I come to is:
$a_n = 5000 * 0,62^n + 1900(...)$
I get stuck, the last part is hard :(

Comment: Close, notice for $a_2$ you have $0.62^0+0.62^1$ in the parentheses, for $a_3$ you have $0.62^0+0.62^1+0.62^2$ in the parentheses..

Comment: Yeah I see that, but I'm not sure of how to express it... I was thinking maybe something like a geometric sequence?? :s

Comment: Yup, that is indeed a geometric sum. I recommend $\sum$ notation if you want the most concise, closed-form answer.

Comment: How does this look:
$a_n = 5000 * 0.62^n + 1900*\sum_{k=0}^{n} 0.62^{n-1} = 5000*0.62^n + 1900*(\frac{0.62^{n} - 1)}{0.62-1})$

Comment: @Kaedos Almost, the sum notation should be $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}0.62^k$. You should probably also make a note that this holds only for $n>0$

Comment: How come $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}0.62^k$?

Isn't $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}0.62^k = \sum_{k=0}^{n} 0.62^{n-1}$?

Comment: @Kaedos No, $n$ is a fixed integer. We want $k$ to vary from $0$ to $n-1$. $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}0.62^{n-1} =0.62^{n-1}+0.62^{n-1}+0.62^{n-1} \ldots \space n \space \text{times} $$ while $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 0.62^k = 0.62^1+0.62^2+\ldots 0.62^{n-1}$$ Not only are both sums unequal, but neither is appropriate for this problem. So you want $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 0.62^k = 1+0.62+0.62^2+\ldots +0.62^{n-1}$$

Comment: Oh!! I get that part now, thanks a lot :)
So the answer is:
$a_n = 5000 * 0.62^n + 1900*\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 0.62^{k}$
But how come $k = 1$, is it possible to set $k = 0$ and then $0.62^{k-1}$?

Comment: @Kaedos No, the sum must start from $k=0$. And I just noticed in a previous comment you represented the sum as $\frac{0.62^n-1}{0.62-1}$. This is also good! It could be seen as less cumbersome for some people.

Comment: My bad, I misread, thought it said $k = 1$. So, just to be clear, is the following the correct answer?

$a_{n} = 5000*0.62^{n} + 1900*\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 0.62^{k}$

Is it possible to rewrite the sum as follows: $1900*\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 0.62^{k} = 1900*\sum_{k=0}^{n} 0.62^{k-1}$?

Comment: @Kaedos Yes to the first question, that is correct. I give it the stamp of approval for what it's worth. No to the second question, as that sum is equal to $\frac{1}{0.62}+1+0.62+\ldots + 0.62^{n-1}$, so you gain an unnecessary $\frac{1}{0.62}$ term.

Answer (score 0):

**hints**
Looks like $a_{n+1} = (1-0.38) a_n + 1900 = 0.62 a_n + 1900$ with $a_0 = 5200$.

In general you should get $a_n = A 0.62^n + B + Cn$, note that
$5200 = a_0 = A + B$ and get other initial conditions and find B and C.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, but it is a good start, $a_1=5200+1900$,$a_2=0.68^2\cdot 5200+1900\cdot 0.68+1900$,$a_3=0.68^3\cdot 5200+1900\cdot 0.68^2+1900\cdot 0.68+1900$, see the pattern?

$$a_n=5200\cdot 0.68^n+1900\cdot\frac{1-0.68^{n-1}}{0.32}$$